# Key differences (pros and cons) between geoprocessing package and geoprocessing service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service, geoprocessing-package

What are the key differences between geoprocessing packages and services?

Comment: What did you find in your research prior to asking this question?  Asking for a list of differences is what makes this too broad for focused Q&A.  They are also a question format that is frequently seen in homework and assignment tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A geoprocessing package is a bundle of files that you can send to somebody else so that they can run the geoprocessing on their own computer.

A geoprocessing service is an internet (web) based service that anybody (or a set of people to whom permissions have been granted) can run the service through their web browser.  The processing actually runs on the server, NOT on the end-users computer.

For a service, an end-user does not need any special software, apart from a web browser, and does not need any software licenses.  However, the person maintaining that service (the admin) must have ArcGIS Server and the relevant (and expensive!) licensing for that.

For a package, an end-user must have the required software (eg, ArcMap) and license(s).  The person distributing the package would also require such a license and software, but it's cheaper and easier to manage than ArcGIS Server.